# USB DVD drive mapped to wrong product

Tags: 16.04, drivers, usb, dvd

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (dual boot w/ Windows)

I picked up this external USB DVD writer, model ECD819-SU

I have successfully plugged it in, burned a CD, and listened to the CD in the car, so at one point everything worked fine without doing anything special.

Now many days later I try to burn another CD and things are strange.

Plugging in the USB DVD drive no longer notifies me of a blank disc in it or otherwise appears in Brasero or file viewer.

After searching for similar problems I come across this technique where I unplug and replug the USB DVD drive, then run this:

```
dmesg | tail
[ 1517.648577] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 10
[ 1562.479656] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[ 1562.621181] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=13fd, idProduct=1040
[ 1562.621186] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1562.621189] usb 3-1: Product: \xffffffc2\xffffff92¬A6þ¾\xffffffc2\xffffff80\xffffffc2\xffffff83/µ\xffffffc2\xffffff85\xffffffc2\xffffff87ðL
[ 1562.621192] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Initio
[ 1562.621195] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 00000000000000000
[ 1562.621919] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1562.622179] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[ 1585.001736] usb 3-1: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
```

Cool so the vendor ID is 13fd and the product ID is 1040.

More searching and I come across http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids which reveals some interesting info:

```
    13fd  Initio Corporation
        0840  INIC-1618L SATA
        0841  Samsung SE-T084M DVD-RW
        ...
        1040  INIC-1511L PATA Bridge   <--- current PID
        1340  Hi-Speed USB to SATA Bridge
        ...
        3940  external DVD burner ECD819-SU3  <--- HEY, this is right!
        3e40  ZALMAN ZM-VE350
```

So that's where I'm stuck. I don't know if the product ID actually changed or has been this way all along. Even though I can see some files with these codes, I would rather not just blindly change values:

```
/sys$ grep -r "13fd" * 2>/dev/null
devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/idVendor:13fd
devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/uevent:PRODUCT=13fd/1040/106
devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/uevent:PRODUCT=13fd/1040/106
```

I assume that 106 following 13fd and 1040 is some kind of driver ID, so I'd have to know what the DVD drive driver ID should be, maybe.

Anyway, any suggestions? Should I edit these things, or use some technique to get Ubuntu to totally forget this info and see if it will deduce the correct product/driver from scratch again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not see any message about the device being recognized as "sr",
then the drive (obviously behind a PATA-USB bridge) is not recognized
as optical drive. Probably it is not detected at all.

A power cycle (with quite old kernel) looks here in dmesg like

```
[...] usb 2-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 82
[...] usb 2-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 90 using ehci-pci
[...] usb 2-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2338
[...] usb 2-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[...] usb 2-1.5: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
[...] usb 2-1.5: Manufacturer: JMicron
[...] usb 2-1.5: SerialNumber: 59CF92A50122
[...] usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[...] scsi78 : usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0
[...] scsi 78:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ASUS     BW-16D1HT        1.01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[...] sr4: scsi3-mmc drive: 48x/48x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[...] sr 78:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr4
[...] sr 78:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 5
```

One can see that the drive's class "CD-ROM", its manufacturer "ASUS", its
drive model id "BW-16D1HT", and its firmware revision "1.01" are reported.
Then some of its oldfashioned CD capabilities are reported and it gets
attached as optical drive /dev/sr4 (and generic SCSI device /dev/sg6).

Your dmesg reports a reset instead, which i do not see here. Your dmesg
mentions "1040", which you found in the web as "PATA Bridge". That would
be the hardware in the drive's box, which makes it appear as USB device
although all optical drives have either PATA or SATA controllers.
(In my case it's by "JMicron".)

Fishiness in your dmesg begins by:

```
[ 1562.621189] usb 3-1: Product: \xffffffc2\xffffff92¬A6þ¾\xffffffc2\xffffff80\xffffffc2\xffffff83/µ\xffffffc2\xffffff85\xffffffc2\xffffff87ðL
```

Why cannot the USB controller tell its model name, like mine does ?

```
[...] usb 2-1.5: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
```

This difference and the reset give me the suspicion that the USB controller
in the drive's box has died.

Comment: Thanks for looking it over! I purchased this drive new just recently, but it was very cheap and from a company I hadn't heard of. You've convinced me even if there is a way to revive it that it's not worth any more time.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with a device showing the identical lsusb info.

`Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13fd:1040 Initio Corporation INIC-1511L PATA Bridge`

I had used this CD/DVD Writer on Mac for a number of years, then I switched to linux & used it there also.

Recently I reinstalled my distros. I was able to burn 1 CD & then I was unable to burn anymore. At that point I noticed the device was shown as PATA Bridge.

However, it is NOT BROKEN as I can still use it to play CDs & it seems to work fine as a player in Archcraft & Manjaro.
Connecting the device to my wife's Win11 computer I was able to burn a CD without issue.

But in multiple Linux CD writing apps it will not work. (xfburn, brasero, gnome cd master, k3b)